# Spring Boot spring.factories vs @Enable annotations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have been using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud for a while, and Spring core for even longer, yet I cannot find a clear rule on which technique to use when creating a framework :

- Spring Boot starter + `spring.factories` file
- Spring Boot starter + `@EnableXxx`
- both

For example :

- the Eureka client starter requires users to import `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-client` AND to add `@EnableEurekaClient` on some configuration class
- On the other hand, adding `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` on the classpath is enough to trigger data source auto configuration. There is no such thing as `@EnableDataSourceAutoConfiguration`
- Somebody who wants to configure caching through configuration properties also needs to add `@EnableCaching` manually

Sometimes the `@EnableXxx` annotated class is included in the code brought by a starter, sometimes not.

I know `@Enable...` is the "pre Spring-Boot" method (technically a good-looking `@Import`), but the fact that `@EnableEurekaClient` exists is proof that it's not deprecated by any mean.

What's the rule there ? I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule (at least from the Spring Cloud perspective).

[Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer) said:

> A candidate rule of thumb is "if something is on the classpath but
>   provides multiple features, you need a way to switch on a subset"
>   I prefer to think of it as "revealing a conscious choice"
>   as opposed to "relying on magic"

I've kind of looked at as starting servers or doing work (like Discovery Client)

Comment: Another factor is if what's being brought in does one thing or multiple things. Add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, and it automatically applies @EnableJpaRepositories, because that's this module does. However, Spring's caching can be pulled in from the Spring Framework without someone having grabbed some starter, hence it has to be activated by choice. To be honest, I would presume a tightly scoped starter like eureka-client would activate itself.